# How to deploy JavaFX in Swing desktop application

Tags: java, swing, deployment, javafx, javafx-2

I managed to embed [JavaFX HTMLEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) inside a Swing desktop application using this [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm), locally in Eclipse all works great.

My question is how to deploy this to our customers? Oracle have a [tutorial for WebStart and Applet deployment](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/deploy_swing_apps.htm) but I see no information for desktop apps.

Currently I copy libs and binaries from my installed JavaFX SDK into my project and include them when I compile distribution:

```
/my/application/lib/javafx/lib/javafxrt.jar
/my/application/lib/javafx/bin/[dll:s from JavaFX Runtime]
```

But this seems very odd, there must be a better way? I need some help here. The thing is that during development in Eclipse I need `javafxrt.jar` on the classpath, so I've copied the jar file because I couldn't see any environment variable like `javafx_home` I could use. But when JavaFX is loaded it tries to load the dlls: from a relative path, that's why I also copied the dlls into my project.

This is problematic for deployment, I rather not ship 32 bits JavaFX Runtime if clients have a 64 bits JVM installed (that won't work I think). Currently our customers only run Windows so for the moment that's not a problem.

Isn't there a way in runtime to check if JavaFX is installed or not, and if so get path to it "dynamically"? Shipping the jar file is no problem, but I'm worried about the platform dependent binaries.

**Update:** WebStart is not an option because we bundle/install the application with an old Windows app that is the predecessor, not all functionality is ported yet so the two applications communicate with a custom made IPC protocol.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the app.  JWS makes it simple to add dependent Jars & natives to the run-time class-path of an application, and can partition the download of natives by platform.

In fact, I'd be surprised if the JavaFX API does not already offer an extension [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) that client apps. can simply link to in their own JNLP launch file.

Comment: Unfortunately WebStart is not an option, see my update. Any other ideas?

Comment: *"Any other ideas?"*  Explain what part of the update cannot be done using JWS.

Comment: In the long run I agree JWS based solution would be good. Though for the moment I was looking for a solution without changing our build/pack/deploy process. We create distribution of both applications bundled with InnoSetup if that's of any importance.

Comment: JWS has an `installer-desc` element for calling native installers, that is just one link beyond the two links I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new JavaFX ant tasks described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_swing_apps_with_integrated). Worked fine for me.

EDIT: Also see native packaging: https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a JavaFX component in java swing application using JFXPanel (javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel).
it is used to embedded JavaFX components in the java swing application.
learn more about JFXPanel at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html

Comment: This is what the tutorial linked in the question says. The question is "how to deploy this to our customers?"

Comment: it's easy to deploy just try it